# DataGridView selected row to display in text boxes

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView`(tblLoggedJobs) that displays a list of jobs logged by a user. I need the admins to be able to update these jobs to display any updates to the job or note if the job is closed.
I would like the program to display the data in the selected ROW to the textboxes to the right, however I'm not sure how to get this data and display it based on the row that is selected.

[image: Get Selected Row to text boxes]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [SelectedRows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectedrows%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property.

Example:

```
if(dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 0) // make sure user select at least 1 row 
{
   string jobId = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value + string.Empty;
   string userId = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value + string.Empty;

   txtJobId.Text = jobId;
   txtUserId.Text = userId;
}
```

Comment: What if the user selected more than one row?

Comment: @Ben "What if the user selected more than one row? "
Properties of the Datagridview -> MultiSelect = False

Comment: Works great! What is the purpose of the "string.Empty" that is added to the end of each variable declaration statement?

Comment: `dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value` return the `Object` so you need to cast it to `String`

Comment: Does that mean that I can swap out `String` with `int` or `DateTime`?

Comment: Yes you can swap it with int, DateTime, etc

Answer (score 10):

[image: Select cellclick event of datagridview]

Add code in cellclick event

```
if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
{
    //gets a collection that contains all the rows
    DataGridViewRow row = this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    //populate the textbox from specific value of the coordinates of column and row.
    txtid.Text = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
    txtfname.Text = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
    txtlname.Text = row.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
    txtcourse.Text = row.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
    txtgender.Text = row.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
    txtaddress.Text = row.Cells[5].Value.ToString();
}
```

For More information use this link [How to Display Selected Row from Datagridview into Textbox using C#](http://www.sourcecodester.com/tutorials/c/6954/how-display-selected-row-datagridview-textbox-using-c.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
private void orderpurchasegridview_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

        int ind = e.RowIndex;
        DataGridViewRow selectedRows = orderpurchasegridview.Rows[ind];
        txtorderid.Text = selectedRows.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        cmbosuppliername.Text = selectedRows.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        cmboproductname.Text = selectedRows.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        txtdate.Text = selectedRows.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
        txtorderquantity.Text = selectedRows.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   private void MyDataGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGrid dg = (DataGrid)sender;
        DataRowView rs = dg.SelectedItem as DataRowView;
        if(rs != null)
        {
            textBoxJobId.Text = rs["JobId"].ToString();
        }
    }
```

spied on the channel https://www.youtube.com/user/saf3al2a/videos

Answer (score 0):

Always use CellEnter event because it will work both with keyboard arrow keys and mouse click.
always use `dataGridView1.SelectedCells.Count > 0` "SelectedCells otherwise you have to select complete row.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if (dataGridView1.SelectedCells.Count > 0) // make sure user select at least 1 cell 
            {


                DataGridToTextboxes(e.RowIndex);


            }
        }

        private void DataGridToTextboxes(int x)
        {
          //try a seperate method to show gridview to text boxes, you can you same method for multiple events.

            string Item1 = dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells[1].Value + string.Empty;

           
            string MinRange = dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells[2].Value + string.Empty;
            string MaxRange = dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells[3].Value + string.Empty;

            string MinStable = dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells[4].Value + string.Empty;
            string MaxStable = dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells[5].Value + string.Empty;

            txtItem.Text = Item1;
            TextMinRange.Text = MinRange;
            TextMaxRange.Text = MaxRange;
            TextMinStable.Text = MinStable;
            TextMaxStable.Text = MaxStable;
        }
```